# Why isn't Paper.js's `smooth: continuous` function working as expected?

Tags: javascript, curve, smoothing, paperjs

[Sketch link](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.15/S/jZHBasMwDIZfRfiShAXXYQRGSk99gcKOTQ+26xGTRAq2ky2EvvucpWyD7VCf5J//1yehhaHsDavYa2uCbljONF3X/yQdDDI0cAA073CKJT9apzuTLjVCfNpgMK6C84vIoRSXfJOdvNrRV/As7oIPjlpzpI6iOVGd1G1S4y3b11jjipkeYBSi/A9SlI9ANoyKmHUj7kcVnNQhnbIaFf8VjY7vrOIDeRssIf+ApwMUQsRmu10M2H7o7NucZj/NdYwqrjtCs8r6b3gVfU8UmnSBMA8mzqkJg8WRRp/AfdYvwGZLpJ/73gRndZLt42mUM7IdyGLwrDpfbp8=)

I want to smooth out the subtraction of these two spheres, as seen in the sketch.  I expected smoothing via the `continuous` type to remove the pointy edges of the sphere, but this didn't happen.  If you change the position of the second circle to a number greater than 100 (circle `v`), then the smoothing works correctly.  How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The smooth function will try to remain course to the original curve, that often means keep some corners.

Instead, you can add some handles to your corner points. That way you will have a good control on the curvature of your drawing.

Comment: I see, so curved splines will retain their pointiness.  Thanks!